# scrollTop function for a dynamically resizing menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I'm trying to create a dynamic menu that automatically resize when the user scrolls  down. After many searches, I've added this script to the head of the html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var header = $(".large");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scroll >= 50) {
            header.removeClass('large').addClass("small");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("small").addClass('large');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

In the html body I've defined the header tag giving the class large as default with no information inside just to have a clean look over the behaviour of the script.

While in the css I defined, according to the definition of the other div in the page, the following characteristics:

```
header.large{position:fixed; width:100%; height:20%; background-color:#00BFFF; top:0px; left:0; z-index:1;}

header.small{position:fixed; width:100%; height:7%; background-color:#000000; top:0px; left:0; z-index:1;}
```

To verify if the script does activate I've changed the colour of the small class, but it still doesn't respond. Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line:

```
var header = $(".large");
```

When you change from a class large to a class small this selector will not work anymore.

Moreover, it's unuseful to cache this value because the seletors change according to the newly class value.

Because you use the window function the document ready (i.e.: $(function() {) is unuseful.

My snippet (instead of header I used a div and some text):

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 50) {
    $('.large').removeClass("large").addClass('small');
  } else {
    $('.small').removeClass('small').addClass("large");
  }
});
```

```css
div.large {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: #00BFFF;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

div.small {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7%;
  background-color: #000000;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<div  class="large">
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb<br/>
    
    bbbbbbbbbbbb<br/>
</div>


a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
```